# SSMS 2005 - Non-aliased column returning different results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I couldn't even think about how to word this title. This is SQL Server 2005

If I do the same query with an alias on a Column, vs without, I get completely different results. It isn't ambiguous.

Example Query:

```
    UPDATE  MyTable
SET     Col1 = Col1 - 1
FROM    DB.dbo.MyTable M
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   DB.dbo.SecondTable B WITH ( NOLOCK )
                 WHERE  B.Col2 = 12345678
                        AND B.Col3 = 1
                        AND B.M-FK = M.M-PK )
        AND M.Col1 > 0
        AND M.Col4 = 87654321;
```

This query I assumed everything to the table directly, and I get a sizable return.

Very similar query, but I don't specify table

```
UPDATE  MyTable
SET     Col1 = Col1 - 1
FROM    DB.dbo.MyTable M
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   DB.dbo.SecondTable B WITH ( NOLOCK )
                 WHERE  Col2 = 12345678
                        AND Col3 = 1
                        AND B.M-FK = M.M-PK )
        AND Col1 > 0
        AND Col4 = 87654321;
```

The 2nd query returns 1.

The *only* mutual column between this is B-ForeignKey => M.PrimaryKey

In my experience I've always assigned columns to an alias, but when someone asked me the above question earlier, I found myself quite confused. If they were ambiguous, SSMS would reject it. However, it actually ran.

So I thought 'maybe' it ignores those columns - Which is weird.
but the 2nd returns -1- row, which adds more confusion.

Can anyone explain exactly why the alias vs non-alias query changes? And why it completes at all, if it's an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, I never refer to tables directly by their db name. I always **Alias** them, as it's easier to read for one, and also makes it quite clear what column I am referring in cases where the same exact column name and datatype are across two or more tables.

Try this instead and stick with the same design going forward and you'll always get the result you expect:

```
UPDATE  m
SET     m.Col1 = m.Col1 - 1
FROM    dbo.MyTable AS m
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   dbo.SecondTable AS b WITH ( NOLOCK )
                 WHERE  b.Col2 = 12345678
                        AND b.Col3 = 1
                        AND b.M-FK = m.M-PK )
        AND m.Col1 > 0
        AND m.Col4 = 87654321;
```

AS oppossed to ...

```
UPDATE  dbo.MyTable
SET     Col1 = Col1 - 1
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   dbo.SecondTable AS b WITH ( NOLOCK )
                 WHERE  b.Col2 = 12345678
                        AND b.Col3 = 1
                        AND b.M-FK = M-PK )
        AND Col1 > 0
        AND Col4 = 87654321;
```

The problem with the 2nd version is SQL may get confused between the two tables, if the two tables *have one or more of the same column definitions.* In fact it may not even run due to those errors! Hence why with Aliasing, I know what table I am referring to and it updates only the columns and the table I want.

Here's a tip:

Think of UPDATE as a "kettle pot cover", where the goodness "of the pot" (the SELECT statement) is inside the pot!

ie:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.col1 = @value1, a.col2 = @value2, etc
FROM dbo.myTable1 AS a
  INNER JOIN dbo.myTable2 as b ON b.col3 = a.col3
  INNER JOIN ...etc..
WHERE ..etc..
```

Note that from the FROM clause it's just like a `SELECT`. And you don't have to UPDATE the first table in your query. You can UPDATE b, or UPDATE c, and so on, without affecting the logic in the query's FROM clause.

So my advice is to write a SELECT query to get the data you want first, get it working and then replace the SELECT with the `UPDATE & SET` depending on what columns you want to change. That way I never get confused in terms of the data I am changing.

I've managed to create massive UPDATE SQL statements this way and get them working almost first time.

Cheers

Comment: Good explanation. I always stick to the alias as well, it was my employee who asked me this question when he compared his script vs mine and the result difference. Not having an actual answer for him, and both of us kind of just 'assuming' SQL Was ignoring his WHERE due to the columns not having a specific table listed, but I was still trying to figure out an 'exact' answer. It seems like it is just SSMS ignoring those fields, though. 

Still no clue how his query got even one result, but yea. I'm willing to agree with your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you could vote my answer, that would also be appreciated @DNorthrup

Answer (score 0):

If any column reference were ambiguous you'd get an error.  Those queries look the same to me but the predicate `Col1 > 0` would potentially filter out different rows after each execution since you're decrementing it.  Also, `B.M-FK` I'm assuming is an artifact of your obfuscation since that'd be interpreted as `B.M - B.FK`.  I'm assuming you mean something like `B.[M-FK]` or `B.M_FK`.

I also see `(NOLOCK)`.  If the data is in flux in `B` that could contribute.

Comment: Hey Ben, they are the exact same except for 3 lines not referencing the alias'd table. I used placeholder names in my above queries. Those aren't the actual names. B.M-FK means B.[B]-Foreign Key, and M.M-PK means M.[M]-Primary Key. Just referencing what the UID it would reflect is.